# ksh - Reading an unset variable into an array using the read command

Tags: linux, shell-script, ksh

I have the following ksh script, where $an_unset_var is an unset variable which is being used for the first time:

```
read -A arr <<< "$an_unset var"
echo ${#an_unset_var}
echo ${#arr[*]}
```

Executing which, I get the following output:

```
0
1
```

Why does reading an unset variable into an array using the read command enter an empty element in the array? Why would this empty element be considered a valid countable element of the array?

**Important Edit:**

Missing underscore in the first line of the script.

```
read -A arr <<< "$an_unset_var"
```

$an_unset_var is the variable.

Comment: Also being discussed on [unix&linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439800/4667)

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think there is an empty element in the array?

```
% mksh
$ read -A arr <<< "$broda $brode $brodi mlatu"
$ print -l $arr
mlatu
$
```

that's with `mksh R56c`; `arr` contains a single element which is why `${#arr[*]}` returns a count of `1`...

Comment: Sorry my bad. $an_unset_variable is a single variable. Duly updated.